# Como fazer todas as imagens com o mesmo tamanho

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Eu estou a usar bootstrap e gostava que as imagens independentemente de qual o tamanho que foram colocadas no servidor ficassem com o mesmo tamanho

https://www.adota-me.com/

Comment: Você pode forçar o width e height das imagens no css. Não é uma boa pratica, mas funciona...

Comment: O que deveria eu fazer?

Comment: Mesma largura, mesma altura, ou vai cortar pra ficar no mesmo formato? Se for cortar, tem que escolher manualmente o alinhamento.

Comment: isto é para um site de anúncios o que parece mais viável para esta situação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS vai resolver seu problema, mas pelo que eu vi no seu site sua imagem tem 3000px de largura, o melhor seria diminuir o tamanho dela no servidor mesmo, viu.

Eu utilizo esse código abaixo pra fazer essa função, em que `$max_x` é a largura final da imagem e `$max_y` sua altura. Note que `$vDestino1` deve ser a imagem original (o arquivo que está subindo) e `$vDestino2` é o caminho onde a imagem pequena será salva.

```
                $max_x = 150;
                $max_y = 150;


                list($width, $height) = getimagesize($vDestino1);
                $original_x = $width;
                $original_y = $height;
                if($original_x > $original_y){
                    $porcentagem = (100 * $max_x) / $original_x;
                }else{
                    $porcentagem = (100 * $max_y) / $original_y;
                }
                $tamanho_x = $original_x * ($porcentagem / 100);
                $tamanho_y = $original_y * ($porcentagem / 100);
                $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($tamanho_x, $tamanho_y);
                switch (strtolower(substr($vDestino1, -3))){
                    case "jpg":

                    $image   = imagecreatefromjpeg($vDestino1);
                    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tamanho_x, $tamanho_y, $width, $height);
                    imagejpeg($image_p, $vDestino2, 90);
                    break;

                    case "gif":

                    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($tamanho_x, $tamanho_y);
                    imagealphablending($image_p, false);
                    imagesavealpha($image_p,true);
                    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image_p, 255, 255, 255, 127);
                    imagefilledrectangle($image_p, 0, 0, $tamanho_x, $tamanho_y, $transparent);

                    $image   = imagecreatefromgif($vDestino1);
                    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tamanho_x, $tamanho_y, $width, $height);
                    imagegif($image_p, $vDestino2);
                    break;

                    case "png":

                    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($tamanho_x, $tamanho_y);
                    imagealphablending($image_p, false);
                    imagesavealpha($image_p,true);
                    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image_p, 255, 255, 255, 127);
                    imagefilledrectangle($image_p, 0, 0, $tamanho_x, $tamanho_y, $transparent);

                    $image   = imagecreatefrompng($vDestino1);
                    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tamanho_x, $tamanho_y, $width, $height);
                    imagepng($image_p, $vDestino2);
                    break;

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para mudar o tamanho de TODAS imagens da página, de uma só vez, tente isso em seu css:

```
img {
width: 800px!important;
height: 600px!important;
}
```

Altere o 800 e 600 para os valores desejados. Você pode, também, alterar o tamanho de todas as imagens que estão dentro de uma div, por exemplo.
O código ficaria assim:

```
div#imagens img {
width: 800px!important;
height: 600px!important;
}
```

E sua div precisaria do id "imagens", como no código

```
<div id="imagens">
<img src="/imagem1.png />
<img src="/imagem2.png />
</div>
```